# PHP sort not working

Tags: php, sorting, explode

I'm trying to sort a string alphabetically. I thought I could explode a string into an array and sort it, but the echo is returning nothing.

```
$schools = "high*low*other*";
$schools = explode("*", $schools);
$schools = sort($schools);
echo $schools[0];
```

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) what `sort()` returns

Comment: Sort doesn't return an array it modifies the array http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php just `sort($schools);`

Comment: Check out my answer, I gave some insight into what actually happens when you call some functions and a way in which you can fix your code. I actually like helping whenever I can, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 5):

[`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) sorts in place (i.e. modifies the array itself A.K.A. the `$schools` variable is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)) so no array is returned. A boolean value is however returned to determine if the sort was successful.

> bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

```
$schools = "high*low*other*";
$schools = explode("*", $schools);
sort($schools);
echo $schools[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by the following code example:

```
<?php
   $schools = "c*d*a";
   $alpha_sorted_array = explode("*", $schools);
   sort($alpha_sorted_array);

   foreach($alpha_sorted_array as $itemToPrint){
     echo("Item: $itemToPrint\n");
   }

?>
```

Basically, you reasign what happens when you use the explode function on the string variable held inside schools, as you know, explode uses the first delimiter, in this case * found inside the initial string $schools to return an array. From this point you can call the sort function on the new array and it will return a sorted array(no resasinging needed for this one, just call sort() on it)

The given output is:

```
Item: a
Item: c
Item: d
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is [natcasesort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

This function sorts values with natural algorithm and case-insensitively.

Comment: Yes! I had an issue where `sort()` wasn't working the same between my local server and another server, despite the PHP versions being exactly the same, and despite passing in the `$flags` argument `SORT_STRING`. This was the only thing that helped.

Comment: @Doggit, I was also facing the issue with sort() function. Glad to know that my little intelligence helped you.